# Query Data for all users and copy to path

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

I was looking for some help in solving this some what perplexing problem. Keep in mind I have tagged this as Swift 3 but you're welcome to answer in any language as the logic is more crucial than the language. 
The issue I am trying to solve is trying to run a query on a nested set of data and pushing the result of the query to a specific child node. 
For clarity here is what the database "scheme" looks like right now.

```
users
 $uid
   $uid_followers
         $uid1 : true 
         $uid2 : true
         $uid3 : true
                .
                .
user_followers
 $uid
       $uid1 : username, userProfilePicture
       $uid2 : username, userProfilePicture
       $uid3 : username, userProfilePicture
```

Basically, I'm trying to query the username and profile picture of users inside every users node and then copy those results into /user_followers/$uid/...
Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to query and update. Can you use something like fan-out (write at multiple places during the client action). When the user follows someone put their username and the profilepicture.

Comment: @vira It's more of a one time thing, for existing users who don't have the updated client.